# Out of bounds Problem with attributedSubstringFromRange

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a NSMutableAttributedString, I need to take substring from it.I use the following code to take substring,

startIndex and endIndex are two long variables.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *currentString = (NSMutableAttributedString *)[attributtedString attributedSubstringFromRange:NSMakeRange(startIndex, endIndex)];
```

But there is an exception if index go higher.
The String Length is always - 21212
I can get output when I given values (9048, 10958)
But after that when I gave values (10958, 12961) there is an Exception,

```
NSConcreteMutableAttributedString attributedSubstringFromRange:: Out of bounds
```

help me in solving this issue, or give me a better way to take substring from a NSMutableAttributedString

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't how NSRange works. It is `location` (startIndex for you) and `length`. Hence the second goes from 10958 to 10958 + 12961 = 23919, which is out of bounds.